# How to rotate a character by 90 degrees in python?

Tags: python, string, character

I'm trying to rotate the character | sideways by 90 degrees, think of a longer - and then print it.

would appreciate the help as to how I can do that?

Comment: Where is this character originally/initially from? And where do you want to do this rotation? Is this an image...? Or a string...? And print it to standard output...? When you say "*rotate*", do you mean with some animation? Why not just print out an em dash "—"? Please [edit] to clarify your question and to provide some sample inputs and expected outputs/behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For converting '|' char to 90 degree, we can replace with  all chars '|' to  '—'  chars.

```py
s1 = "Example | text | with | horizontal | string"

def RotateCharacter90(s1):
    s2 = s1.replace( "|", "—")
    return s2

print(RotateCharacter90(s1))

""" OUTPUT: Example — text — with — horizontal — string """
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. I'm trying to literally rotate a single character by 90 degrees

Comment: Hi @Shakshouk, I have just changed the solution for your revision. Does it meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just print an em dash, "—"? In many fonts, an em dash is as long as the font's letters are tall.

Here's some example code that "rotates" the "|" symbol in the console in a complete circle for a loading animation by replacing it with em dashes and forward and backward slashes.

```py
import time
import sys

def loadingAnimation():
    #Run for 10 seconds
    timeToRun = time.time() + 10
    while time.time() < timeToRun:
        wheelAnim = ['|','/','—','\\']
        for frame in wheelAnim:
            sys.stdout.write('\rLoading... %s' % frame)
            #Hold each frame for 0.15 seconds
            time.sleep(0.15)
            sys.stdout.flush()
          
    sys.stdout.write('\rLoading... complete.\n')
  
loadingAnimation()
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll add a code block showing how to print an em dash to the console.